# How do I start Jenkins on port 8000?

Tags: java, jenkins

With Hudson, running `java -jar hudson-3.0.0-bundled.war -httpPort=8000` worked. I've tried the same with Jenkins, but it still runs on port 8080:

```
$ java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=8000
Running from: /home/user/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Sep 25, 2013 12:22:14 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: /home/user/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Sep 25, 2013 12:22:15 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=8080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a '-' missing in your command line.
From [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins): "--httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"

So use `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8000` instead of `java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=8000`

Answer (score 1):

Checking my jenkins init file I think you need --httpPort=$JENKINS_PORT. Have you tried with two dashes before httpPort?

Whether port 8000 is a sensible choice is a whole other question!